# Put View Into Circular Layout Corner Android

Tags: android, android-viewgroup

[image]I am made a semi circle custom layout. In which i want to put the my view into the outer surface of the semi circle. but it i not showing exactly i want.

I the below code I have override the OnLayout method of view group.
I have posted my code below:-

```
@Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
int mAngleRange = 180;
        final int childs = getChildCount();

        float totalWeight = 0f;

        for (int i = 0; i < childs; i++) {
            totalWeight += 1;
        }

        float startAngle = 270;
        final int width = getWidth();
        final int height = getHeight();

        for (int i = 0; i < childs; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);

            final LayoutParams lp = layoutParams(child);

            final float angle = mAngleRange / totalWeight * 1;

            final float centerAngle = startAngle + angle / 2f;

            final int x;
            final int y;

            if (childs > 1) {
                int radius = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.item_radius);
                x = (int) (radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(centerAngle)) + 0);
                y = (int) (radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(centerAngle))) + height / 2;
            } else {
                x = width / 2;
                y = height / 2;
            }


            final int left = lp.width != LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ? x : 0;
            final int top = lp.height != LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ? y : 0;
            final int right = lp.width != LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ? x + child.getMeasuredWidth() : width;
            final int bottom = lp.height != LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ? y + child.getMeasuredHeight() : height;

            Log.d(CircularOverlayLayout.class.getName(), "left =" + left + " top =" + top + " right =" + right + " bottom = " + bottom);
            child.layout(left, top, right, bottom);


            startAngle += angle;

        }
    }

<com.trignodev.customuidemo.CircularOverlayLayout
        android:id="@+id/normalWithRange"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <View
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#ff0000" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#00ff00" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#0000ff" />

    </com.trignodev.customuidemo.CircularOverlayLayout>
```